# Problems with the result of all promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have the following code that does not correctly return all the promises, any idea what is happening?

```js
      pdfjs.getDocument(file).promise.then((docData) => {
            const pageCount = docData._pdfInfo.numPages;

            const outlinePromises = docData.getOutline().then((outline) => { return outline })

            const pagePromises = Array.from(
                { length: pageCount },
                (_, pageNumber) => {
                    return docData.getPage(pageNumber + 1).then((pageData) => {
                        return pageData.getTextContent().then((textContent) => {
                            //console.log(pageData)
                            return textContent.items.map(({ str }) => str).join(" ");
                        });
                    });
                }
            )
            
            return Promise.all([outlinePromises, pagePromises]).then((response) => {
                setOutline(response[0])
                setPages(response[1]);
                console.log(response)
            });
        });
```

As you can see, the first element of the promises array is returned correctly while the second is returned with *"Promise {:"*, I don't understand its meaning

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises, not an array of arrays of promises. You'll have to write

```
return Promise.all([Promise.all(outlinePromises), Promise.all(pagePromises]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Bergi has pointed out, you are provided a two-dimensional array to `Promise.all`. You can either [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals) the nested arrays:

```
return Promise.all([...outlinePromises, ...pagePromises])
```

...or unpack them use [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
return Promise.all([outlinePromises, pagePromises].flat())
```